# How to interpolate based on previous behaviour python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have a `DataFrame` tracking Temperatures based on time.
it looks like this :
[image: 1]

For a few days there was a problem and it shows 0 so the plot looks like this:
[image: 2]

I have replaced the 0 with nans and then used interpolate method but the result is not what I need even I used `method = time` I get this:
[image: 3]

So how can I use a customised interpolation or something to correct this based on previous behaviour?
Thank you

Comment: If you leave the NaNs I think matplotlib plotting routines will just leave a gap, which is what you really have (a gap in the data). I don't like show pretend data for times where you don't have any data, but that's just me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not interpolate. I would just take N elements before the gap and after, compute the average temperature and fill the gap with random values using a normal distribution around the average value (and you can use the std too)

Answer (score 0):

The variances between the frames indicates true variable values missing or not calculated within the set range.
<1,2/,3,...?>="unknown""unknowns"/^@'table'/open(set)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).